# Using "for xml" to format SQL results that include results that are NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL query basically as follows:

```
DECLARE @BODY1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @BODY1 = CAST((SELECT td = Name + '</td><td>' + Number + '</td><td>' + Address + '</td>'
FROM
(
   SELECT
       Name, Number, Address
   FROM
       Table1
) as Sub
FOR XML PATH('tr'), type) AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SET @BODY1 = '<TABLE CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="3" BORDER="1">'+
'<TR><TH>Name</TH><TH>Number</TH><TH>Address</TH></TR> + 
+ REPLACE(REPLACE(@Body1, '&lt;','<'), '&gt;','>') + '</TABLE>'

EXEC MSDB.DBO.SP_SEND_DBMAIL
@PROFILE_NAME = 'NAME',
@RECEPIENTS = 'NAME@DOMAIN.COM',
@BODY = @Body1,
@SUBJECT = 'Details',
@BODY_FORMAT = 'HTML',
@EXECUTE_QUERY_DATABASE = 'NAME';
```

The data I have can be summarised as follows:

```
NAME        NUMBER      ADDRESS
Bob         12345       1 Street, Town
John        23456       
Scott       34567       3 Avenue, City
```

When I run this code which sends me an email containing the results of the query, I only get Bob and Scott's record. This example is simplified, but if there are any rows that do not have data in each field then they do not show in the email.

I've read somewhere that perhaps this is due to needing another variable as part of the XML code, but I can't quite put my finger on what it is. Please can someone assist me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: It is better to compose an email as (X)HTML via SQL Server's XQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to prepare for the entire output of this expression to be `NULL`:

```
SET @BODY1 = CAST((SELECT td = Name + '</td><td>' 
    + Number + '</td><td>' 
    + Address + '</td>' ...
```

A couple of ways to handle that. You can use `COALESCE` to convert NULL to empty string:

```
SET @BODY1 = CAST((SELECT td = COALESCE(Name, '') + '</td><td>'
  + COALESCE(Number, '') + '</td><td>'
  + COALESCE(Address, '') + '</td>' ...
```

Or `CONCAT()`, which does that for you:

```
SET @BODY1 = CAST((SELECT td = CONCAT
  (Name, '</td><td>', Number, '</td><td>', Address, '</td>') ...
```

There are also certainly other approaches to your entire problem space that are a lot less messy, but this is at least a start to get your missing row back.

For example, on SQL Server 2017, you can use `STRING_AGG()` and `CONCAT_WS()`:

```
SELECT @BODY1 = '<table ...>
  <TR><TH>Name</TH><TH>Number</TH><TH>Address</TH></TR><tr>' 
    + STRING_AGG('<td>'+CONCAT_WS('</td><td>',Name,Number,Address)
    +'</td>','</tr><tr>') + '</tr></table>'
FROM dbo.Table1;
```

This is also, admittedly, ugly. Another way:

```
SELECT @BODY1 = '<table ...>
  <TR><TH>Name</TH><TH>Number</TH><TH>Address</TH></TR>
  <tr>' + td + '</table>' 
FROM 
(
  SELECT td FROM
  (
    SELECT Name = COALESCE(Name, ''), 
      Number = COALESCE(Number,''), 
      Address = COALESCE(Address,'')
    FROM dbo.Table1
  ) AS cp UNPIVOT(td FOR cols IN (Name, Number, Address)) AS up
  FOR XML PATH('tr')
) AS x(td);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your primary issue is that `+` will return null if any of the values are null. So you could use either `ISNULL` or `CONCAT`

But this is in any case not the correct way to create XML. You should just unpivot the values and use `FOR XML` properly.

```sql
DECLARE @BODY1 NVARCHAR(MAX) =
(
   SELECT
       ISNULL(v.td, '') AS td
   FROM
       Table1
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      (Name),
      (Number),
      (Address)
   ) v(td)
   FOR XML PATH('tr')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following XQuery based approach that gererates XHTML for the email.

Notable points:

- No strings concatenation.
- No worries for NULL values.
- Very easy to create, very easy to maintain.
- UI styling is controlled via CSS.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Name] VARCHAR(20), Number CHAR(5), [Address] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Name, Number, Address) VALUES
('Bob  ', '12345' ,'1 Street, Town'),
('John ', '23456' , NULL),
('Scott', '34567' ,'3 Avenue, City');

DECLARE @xhtmlBody XML
   , @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
   , @tableCaption VARCHAR(30) = 'Customers list';

SET @xhtmlBody = (SELECT (
SELECT * FROM @tbl FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root'))
.query('<html><head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            (: including embedded CSS styling :)
            <style>
            table <![CDATA[ {border-collapse: collapse;  width: 300px;} ]]>
            th <![CDATA[ {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} ]]>
            th, td <![CDATA[ { text-align: left; padding: 8px;} ]]>
            tr:nth-child(even) <![CDATA[ {background-color: #f2f2f2;} ]]>
            #green <![CDATA[ {background-color: lightgreen;} ]]>
         </style>
         </head>
         <body>
<table border="1">
   <caption><h2>{sql:variable("@tableCaption")}</h2></caption>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
{
    for $row in /root/row
    return <tr>
            <td>{data($row/ID)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/Name)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/Number)}</td>
            <td>{data($row/Address)}</td>
        </tr>
}
</tbody></table></body></html>'));

SELECT @xhtmlBody;

SET @body = CAST(@xhtmlBody AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

**Output**
[image]