# Adding an embedded link whose URL contains a variable to an HTML table created via SQL

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, hyperlink

I'm currently working on creating an SQL Server job that will send out e-mails every x minutes if there is new information in a table. These e-mails contain information on the table, as well as a hyperlink to one of our sites. I'm trying to embed the hyperlink so it's easier on the eyes, but the problem is that the link needs to be dynamic. (url.com/thing/(data from a table))

Here's the important code I have so far

```
SET @tableHTML =  
    N'
    <body>
        <H3>table header</H3>
    </body> 

    <table class="tg">
    <table border="1">
      <th>Link column header</th>' +

CAST((Select
            td = '<a href="url.com/'+CAST(t.id AS varchar)+'">embedded link</a>'
        from (
                select
                distinct
                tn.id as id
                
                from database.tableName as tn
                
                where
                tn.id is not null
            ) as t
        FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>' ;
```

and the method for sending the emails:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @recipients= @listOfRecipients,
    @subject = @emailSubject,
    @body = @tableHTML,
    @body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

With the current code I have, I'm getting an output of `'<a href="url.com/t.id">embedded link</a>'` in the sent emails, instead of my goal: 'embedded link'

Has anyone had any luck with this in the past?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: It is better to use SQL Server's XQuery for your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69036797/using-for-xml-to-format-sql-results-that-include-results-that-are-null/69037193#69037193

Comment: Seriously this is the wrong place to be sending emails. This is a database, for storing data. Put your email notifications in a service where you can have full control over your email and won't cause performance issues with your database.

Comment: Also `CAST(t.id AS varchar)` is just [a really bad idea - specify the length!](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: When you try and embed HTML in XML it will get escaped, even if you are just using it for string concat. A dirty solution it to unescape it, but again this is the wrong place to be doing this. You can debug your code by selecting the output instead of emailing it and you'll then see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `td` is just a string, so it's being placed inside quotes `""`. You could cast it to `xml`, but it's much easier to just generate the XML nodes properly.

```sql
SET @tableHTML = N'
<body>
    <H3>table header</H3>
</body> 

<table class="tg">
    <table border="1">
      <th>Link column header</th>' +

    (SELECT
       [td/a/@href] = CONCAT('url.com/', t.id)
       [td/a/text()] = 'embedded link'
     FROM database.tableName as tn
     WHERE tn.id IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY
       tn.id
     FOR XML PATH('tr')
    ) +
    N'
    </table>
</table>
';
```

It's also not necessary to cast `int` if you use `CONCAT`, and if you remove `, TYPE` then you also don't need to cast `xml` as it just returns `nvarchar`.